# wp_enqueue_scripts hook is not working in the plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress plugin, I'm trying to load some CSS files using WordPress wp_enqueue_scripts hook but for some unknown reason, it is not loading up

here is my code

```
<?php
function xyz_scripts(){
   $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
   wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', $plugin_url . 'assets/css/style.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','xyz_scripts');


function xyz_admin_menu(){
   add_menu_page('XYZ Plugin','XYZ','manage_options','xyz-menu','xyz_menu_options','',200);
}

add_action('admin_menu','xyz_admin_menu');


function xyz_menu_options(){
   ?>

    <h2>XYZ Plugin</h2>
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <label>Field</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">

   <?php
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

use the admin_enqueue_scripts hook instead of the wp_enqueue_scripts hook.